# creating new variables in sas

Tags: variables, sas, format, new-operator

I am trying to create 3 new variables and have used this code however keep getting an error in my log, I am not sure what this issue is:

```
    Data birthdata
    SET birthdata;

    native=.;
    if race=3 THEN native=1;
    if race=1 THEN native=0;

    aarace=.;
    if race=2 then aarace=1;
    if race=1 then aarace=0;

   nonwhite=.;
   if (1<race=.) then nonwhite=1;
   if race=1 then nonwhite=0;


  label native  = "Maternal race"
  aarace  = "Maternal race"
  nonwhite = "Maternal race";

 FORMAT native native. aarace aarace. nonwhite nonwhite.;

 run;
```

`

Comment: What is the error they you get?  Note the condition in that next to last IF statement looks very strange and it probably not at all what you are looking for.  Is your goal to create the new variables with three possible values? 1 or 0 or missing? Or would you rather they just have two possible values? 1 or 0.

Comment: I am trying to Create new variables for African American mothers vs White mothers and Other mothers vs White mothers; The error states  the format NATIVE/aarace/nonwhite was not found or could not be loaded.

Comment: Why did you try to attach the formats if you did not create the formats.  What is wrong with just displaying the values as 1 or 0?  As to Mother's is every observation in the dataset a mother? Or is there some other variable you should be checking in addition to RACE?

Answer (score 1):

You missed ; in first line of data step.